# A simple error in jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hover on `.menu li` all of  `a` take this class. 
I want to hover on `.menu li` so that just his child `a` takes the class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Menu is hover
    $('.menu li').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('liHoverMnue');
        $('.menu li a').addClass('aHoverMnue');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('liHoverMnue');
        $('.menu li a').removeClass('aHoverMnue');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this` keyword again

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Menu is hover
    $('.menu li').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('liHoverMnue');
        $(this).find('a').addClass('aHoverMnue');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('liHoverMnue');
        $(this).find('a').removeClass('aHoverMnue');
    });
});
```

You could also chain it

```
$(this).addClass('liHoverMnue').find('a').addClass('aHoverMnue');
```